# Trajectory of photons in Schwarzschild coordinates 2D + t

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, differential-geometry, geodesics

I'm french and my english is awfull, excuse me for this. I hope you could however understand my question.

I'm looking for a formula of trajectory of photons in Schwarzschild coordinates. For example in only 1D+t the trajectory is given by :

$$t(r)= \pm \frac{1}{c}\left[r+Rs.ln\mid \frac{r}{Rs}-1\mid \right] $$

(Rs is the Schwarzschild radius, absolute value is for inside and outside and 
+/- is for ingoing and outgoing nul geodesics)

**I'm interrested in a 2D+t version**. Maybe  $t(r)$ and $\theta(r)$ with an initial direction ? I dont know… Something that give the trajectory in space-time (not only 2D space curvature).

Remember I'm awfull also in maths and I only use $y=f(x)$ formulas... don't waste your time in démonstrations I will not understand.

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is a [formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6508) for $r(\theta)$ in terms of Weierstrass elliptic functions. I’m not aware of formulas involving time. I think people tend to just integrate the differential equations numerically.

Comment: Are you aware that many differential equations can’t be solved analytically? Having a formula is relatively rare.

Comment: This paper is too complicated for me, sorry. Do you know where I can find, if it exists, an example of plot 2D+t solved numerically ?

Comment: If you have Mathematica, maybe this? https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GeodesicsInSchwarzschildSpace/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It’s not really what I expected (2D+t) but it may help me. The problem is that I don’t understand how to use it... Why is the angular momentum value [0;5]? what means the difference between K=+/-1 ? (particle and timelike is the same for me). Maybe I’m too noob...